# how to define custom table name in one-to-many relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF Core and have 3 entities: `FormableLineEntity , LabLineEntity, FileRelatedEntity`.
Say `FormableLineEntity` has a collection of `FileRelatedEntities`, and `LabLineEntity` has a collection of `FileRelatedEntities`.

Here are pieces of the Contexts:

```
public class FormManagerContext : DbContext
{
    private IConfigurationRoot m_config;

    public FormManagerContext(IConfigurationRoot p_config, DbContextOptions<FormManagerContext> p_options) : base(p_options)
    {
        m_config = p_config;
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder p_optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(p_optionsBuilder);
        string connectionString = m_config["DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString"];
        p_optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ServiTechDatabaseMain"));
    }
    public DbSet<FormableEntity> Forms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FormableLineEntity> FormableLines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder p_builder)
    {
        p_builder.Entity<QuotationEntity>();
        base.OnModelCreating(p_builder);

        p_builder.Entity<FormableEntity>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        });
        p_builder.Entity<FormableLineEntity>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        });
    }
}
```

Where `FormableEntity` has `public ICollection<RelatedFileEntity> RelatedFiles { get; } = new List<RelatedFileEntity>();`

```
public class LabContext : DbContext
{
    private IConfigurationRoot m_config;

    public LabContext(IConfigurationRoot p_config, DbContextOptions<LabContext> p_options) : base(p_options)
    {
        m_config = p_config;
    }

    public DbSet<LabItemEntity> LabItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LabMainEntity> LabMains { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LabLineEntity> LabLines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder p_optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(p_optionsBuilder);
        string connectionString = m_config["DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString"];
        p_optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ServiTechDatabaseMain"));
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder p_builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(p_builder);

        p_builder.Entity<LabItemEntity>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        });
        p_builder.Entity<LabLineEntity>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        });
        p_builder.Entity<LabMainEntity>(b =>
        {
            b.Property(u => u.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");
        });
    }
}
```

Where `LabLineEntity` also has `public ICollection<RelatedFileEntity> RelatedFiles { get; } = new List<RelatedFileEntity>();`

When I update my DB using `dotnet ef database update -c FormManagerContext Context` its ok.

When then I udpate using `dotnet ef database update -c LabContext` it complains that:

> There is already an object named 'RelatedFileEntity' in the database.

- I can't find how to enforce EF to name these tables using my custom names?
- Maybe use one table? since the only thing that changed is the FK name. Is it possible?

Solutions? Regards!

Comment: It seems like you have multiple DbContexts (AContext and BContext). Can you post code for those?

Comment: @kimbaudi sorry for the VERY late reply, I was out of country.
I have edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

These are different entities, therefore are mapped to different tables.
When creating a table for "RelatedFiles", you cannot map one property (foreign key) to multiple tables.